# Why does code not follow the conditions of my if statement

Tags: python

The task at hand was to print out the minumum number in a loop and the loop stops when a negative number is entered however my min variable   prints out the negative number that I use to stop the loop

```
sum = 0
x = 0
counter = 0
maximum = 0
mini = 0
while x >= 0:
 counter = counter + 1
 x = int(input('enter a postive number:'))
  if x > 0:
  sum = sum + x
  avg = sum/counter
 maximum = max(x, maximum)
 mini=min(x,mini)
print(maximum)
print(sum)
print(avg)
print(mini)
```

Comment: please fix your code indentation your code does not work because of that! Further, it will be easier on everyone if you use the 4 white space convention to indent python code!

Answer (score 1):

I think, based on the way you have it and my understanding of what you are trying to achieve, something like this might work.

```
sum = 0
x = 0
counter = 1
maximum = 0
mini = 0
while x >= 0:
    x = int(input('enter a postive number:'))
    if counter == 1 and x < 0:
        avg = x
        maximum = x
        sum = x
        mini = x
        break
    elif counter == 1:
        mini = x
    if x < 0:
        break
    counter = counter + 1
    sum = sum + x
    avg = sum/counter
    maximum = max(x, maximum)
    mini=min(x,mini)
print(maximum)
print(sum)
print(avg)
print(mini)
```